# Redux initial state not set if retrieved from server with fetch

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux and React and I'm trying to write some basic code. I got a problem that looks silly but I can't resolve.

This is the snippet

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import reducer from './reducers'

const store = createStore(reducer,getInitialState())

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
registerServiceWorker();


function getInitialState(){
  const headers = new Headers()
  var url = 'http://fluxy.mulvm.ie.ibm.com:80'
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/hal+json')
  fetch(`${url}/api/listEnvironmentResources`, { method: 'GET', headers: headers }).then(
      function(response){
        return response.json();
      }
  ).then(jsonData => {
    return {
      environmentRecords : jsonData._embedded.environmentRecordResources
    }
  });
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to set the initial state getting data from the server side. But the store continued to be initialized with the empty value defined in the reducer.
If I try to set that using a function but with internal data instead (like returning a pre-defined object) that works. Is there any limitation on operation like this?

Thanks,
Michele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re trying to use the return value of an asynchronous function, which will not work, so even before the server returns data your application will continue with execution.

A solution could be to initialize the store and call `ReactDOM.render` in the success callback of fetch, then you would be sure of having the data.

**For example:**

```
then(jsonData => {
  const initialState = {
    environmentRecords : jsonData._embedded.environmentRecordResources
  }
  const store = createStore(reducer, initialState)

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('react')
  );     
});
```

*Or,* if you don't mind the app being initialized without data, and then being re-rendered when the request completes you can add an action that accepts the full data, which then is handled in a reducer.

Something in the lines of:

```
const rehydrateAction = data => {
  return {
    type: 'REHYDRATE',
    payload: data,
  };
};

const appReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'REHYDRATE') {
    return action.payload;
  }
  // ...
  return state;
}
then(jsonData => {
  const initialState = {
    environmentRecords : jsonData._embedded.environmentRecordResources
  }
  store.dispatch(rehydrateAction(initialState));
})
```

Comment: I feared something similar. I think I'd go with the second way, looks more clean. Thanks!